# Why java recursively calling function can run forever even though StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, jvm

I met the following problem in a Java exam, why following recursively calling a function can run forever even though StackOverflowError?

```java
public class Solution {
    static int i = 0;

    public static void f(){
        System.out.println(i++);
        try {
            f();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            f();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f();
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why JVM can still run when I've exhausted all call stack memory? **Is there any reference, like JVM specification or JVM source code, can explain above phenomenon?**

Comment: It runs forever because you catch the stackoverflowerror exception and call the function again. In effect, it's an inifinite loop.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Why? Since I've exhaust the call stack memory, how can JVM still run?

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, but it will take a very long time to terminate. Each time an `f()` call throws a `StackOverflowError`, you catch it and make another `f()` call that is not in a `try` block. Eventually that call will also throw a `StackOverflowError`, and then the current call is finished. If the stack can reach a maximum depth of `d`, then `f()` will be called approximately `2^d` times before the whole program terminates. Since `d` is likely on the order of a few hundred to a few thousand, it will not terminate in our lifetimes, but it is not theoretically infinite.

Comment: *"Since I've exhaust the call stack memory, how can JVM still run?"* So your question is, how is it even possible to catch a `StackOverflowError` and recover from it at all? That's a much different question to why this function takes "forever" to run.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, I want to understand this phenomena.

Comment: @kaya3 Is there any reference for his saying? Like JVM Specification?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3

Comment: You haven't exhausted memory. You have only exhausted this thread's stack.

Comment: To second @kaya3, we can insert an artificial limit on the stack depth, throwing the `StackOverflowError` manually when a certain limit has been reached and experiment with that limit, see https://ideone.com/tTZFkP It clearly demonstrates the nonlinear nature of the problem. With the actual JVM’s stack size, it’s still finite in theory but takes way too long for a human to perceive the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm neither java nor jvm expert, but I think adding a extra `recursive depth` output can show exactly what is going on with the call stack.

```java
public class Solution {
  static int i = 0;

  public static void f(int depth) {
    System.out.println(i++);
    System.out.println(String.format("depth=%d", ++depth));
    try {
      f(depth);
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      f(depth);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(1);
  }
}
```

In my test, typical output is

```sh
...more
java.lang.StackOverflowError
161735
depth=3745
161736
depth=3746
161737
java.lang.StackOverflowError
161738
java.lang.StackOverflowError
161739
java.lang.StackOverflowError
161740
depth=3744
161741
depth=3745
...more
```

`StackOverflowError` is thrown because jvm is considering a size limit(1M by default?) of stack memory has reached, but the exception is caught, so the recursion is not stopped, it still tries to call, jvm throw away the recent 1 or 2 problematic calls, and then try continue, so the `depth` value goes around the same maximum value again and again.

I think this way the OP can understand why `i` is increasing without any problem. *I've exhaust the call stack memory* -- you haven't, you nearly exhaust, but jvm always cleared latest few calls to avoid exhaust.